# Glossaries and Leipzig - Displaying short description twice

Tags: glossaries, leipzig

I have a document that is using interlinear glossing using the [leipzig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/leipzig) package. I wish to use the glossary style: `mcolsindex`. However, this causes the glossary to print the short description twice in the glossary itself. I would like to just print `short-long`.

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage[nomain,nonumberlist,smallcaps]{glossaries} 

\usepackage{leipzig}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\newleipzig{und}{u}{undergoer} %custom leipzig acronym

\makeglossaries
\glsunsetall %used to surpress the full printing of an abbreviation in the first call.

\begin{document}  
\printglossary[style=mcolindex]

leipzig uses: {\Erg} vs {\Acc}
Custom abbreviation of undergoer: {\Und}

\end{document}
```

This produces a glossary as follows:
[image]

If I use: `\setacronymstyle{short-long}` in the preamble it suppresses the second printing but only for custom leipzig entries. (I would post an image but do not have the reputation for two images.)  This is clearly something to do with the defined styles in the leipzig package.

Could anybody suggest a workaround that would remove these?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new style based on `mcolsindex` that doesn't show the symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomain,nonumberlist,smallcaps]{glossaries}

\usepackage{leipzig}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\newglossarystyle{mcolindexnosym}{%
  \setglossarystyle{mcolindex}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
     \item\glsentryitem{##1}\glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}%
     \glstreepredesc \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space
##2%
  }%
}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\newleipzig{und}{u}{undergoer} %custom leipzig acronym

\makeglossaries
\glsunsetall %used to surpress the full printing of an abbreviation in the first call. 

\begin{document}
\printglossary[style=mcolindexnosym]

leipzig uses: {\Erg} vs {\Acc}
Custom abbreviation of undergoer: {\Und}

\end{document}
```

Note that this definition uses a command from `glossaries` v4.26. For earlier versions just replace `\glstreepredesc` with `\space`.

[image: image of document]

Answer (score 2):

I'll add an answer for leipzig 2.0 (which has just been added to CTAN, 2017-06-16).

A multicolumn glossary style has been included in the package. It is based on the `mcolalttree` style of the glossaries package, rather than `mcolindex`. The easiest way to set the style for the glossary of abbreviations is to use a package option, as in this MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage[mcolblock]{leipzig} % simplified package inclusion in abstract!

\makeglossaries

\newleipzig{und}{u}{undergoer} %custom leipzig acronym

\begin{document}  

\printglosses % or \printglossaries, to print all glossaries

leipzig uses: {\Erg} vs {\Acc}
Custom abbreviation of undergoer: {\Und}

\end{document}
```

And the output looks like this:

[image]

You can of course still define your own style if you want, instead of using the block styles that leipzig pre-defines.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not to do with the Leipzig package nor is it to do with mcols; rather it is a part of the style `index'. Index displays three entries in the glossary, the abbreviation, the symbol and the long description. For the case of these entries the abbreviation and the symbol are identical. What needs to be done is some way of suppressing the symbol from appearing.

One solution is to edit the style sheet for `index' found in the glossary-tree.sty as part of the glossaries package. Simply remove the reference to the symbol from index environment, i.e. comment out line 58.

This has fixed the problem, although there is probably a more elegant solution.

Comment: It's better to define a new style than edit the code.